# HighCharts Multiple Point selection - access/update getSelectedPoints array immediately after point select

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a HighCharts linegraph where I am allowing multiple point selections. After each selection/de-selection is made, I want to perform an action based on all currently selected points.

I'm triggering off of the plotoptions.line.point.events.select (or .click) events, which returns the latest point selected. However, the array returned by chart.getSelectedPoints() apparently doesn't get updated until after the .select or .click event completes. So I cannot use chart.getSelectedPoints() *inside* the event.

Here's an exerpt from this example demonstrating the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/joelion/QJ75h/

```
   plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            point: {
                events: {
                    select: function() {
                        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

                        var selectedPointsStr = "";

                        // when is the chart object updated? after this function finshes?
                        var selectedPoints = chart.getSelectedPoints();
                        $.each(selectedPoints, function(i, value) {
                            selectedPointsStr += "<br>"+value.category;
                        });

                        $report.html(selectedPointsStr);                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a way force the chart getSelectedPoints() array immediately after a point select? Or maybe another event that fires after the array is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create array with selected points, and just push/overwrite points which are inside. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QJ75h/2/

```
var $report = $('#report'),
    selectedPoints = [];

// create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {},
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            point: {
                events: {
                    select: function (event) {
                        var chart = this.series.chart;

                        var selectedPointsStr = "";
                        if (event.accumulate) {
                            selectedPoints.push(this);
                        } else {
                            selectedPoints = [this];
                        }
                        $.each(selectedPoints, function (i, value) {
                            selectedPointsStr += "<br>" + value.category;
                        });
                        $report.html(selectedPointsStr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what I implemented soon after my post. 

However, I ended going up with another solution. The reason I was doing this was so that when a user clicks a point, data for a 2nd chart is dynamically loaded and drawn on a 2nd chart. But i found that when doing multiple-point selections, it was slow and distracting for the 2nd graph to redraw after every point click. So I just added a button to force-draw the 2nd chart, after selecting points in the first graph. The button function is able to use the normal getSelectedPoints() function.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Good job then!

Answer (score 0):

If `chart.getSelectedPoints()` returns all the other points selected and the `this` in the `select` callback is the point that was just selected, why not just combine them to get all the selected points?

```
select: function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    // when is the chart object updated? after this function finshes?
    var selectedPoints = chart.getSelectedPoints();
    selectedPoints.push(this); // now it's got all the points!

    var selectedPointsStr = "";
    $.each(selectedPoints, function(i, value) {
        selectedPointsStr += "<br>"+value.category;
    });

    $report.html(selectedPointsStr);                            
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QJ75h/2/).

**Or**, you could resort to a little `setTimeout` action:

```
select: function() {

    setTimeout(function(){

        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

        // when is the chart object updated? after this function finshes?
        var selectedPoints = chart.getSelectedPoints();

        var selectedPointsStr = "";
        $.each(selectedPoints, function(i, value) {
            selectedPointsStr += "<br>"+value.category;
        });

        $report.html(selectedPointsStr);                            
    }, 100);
}
```

Another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJ75h/3/).

Comment: I almost implemented your first option (see response to PawełFus). I had also thought about your second solution but didn't think it would work. I assumed that the reason getSelectedPoints() wasn't working wasn't because of timing, but because it wasn't actually updated until _after_ the "select" or "click" events. The 100ms timeout seems to work, but it's a bit hacky, and I would hate to rely on timeouts where I can't actually control the timing of the array updates. Anyway, I ended up with an asynchronous scheme where I use a separate button that calls getSelectedPoints().