# getSelectedPoints array delay problem in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to access to `getSelectedPoints` array on `click` event but there is a delay i get the previous selected points and to solve that now i am using `setTimeout` function *as shown code below* but this is not a solving; Because i can not expect when points are selection finished.
I have seen this question

> [HighCharts Multiple Point selection - access/update getSelectedPoints array immediately after point select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249385/highcharts-multiple-point-selection-access-update-getselectedpoints-array-imme)

but it's solve the problem in **JQuery** and old version of **hightcharts** that has `select` event and it's deprecated in new versions of hightcharts. I need answer to be in **javascript** and **hightcharts** v8.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
            events: {
                click: function(event) {
                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(this.divElement.nativeElement,this.options);

                    chart.getSelectedPoints().forEach(point=>{
                        setTimeout(()=>{
                            // do something here
                          },500);

                    });
                                       
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where have you found the information that the `select` event is deprecated? It's not true, the event is fully supported - API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events.select

And the demo which shows how to get the array of selected points:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uq4nrtky/

```
  point: {
    events: {
      select: function() {

        var selectedPoints = chart.getSelectedPoints()
        selectedPoints.push(this);

        console.log(selectedPoints)
      }
    }
  }
```